# Is there any way to completely empty your inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a very OCD and I'm sick of having all this junk in my inventory. Does anyone know if there is anyway to remove these items or completely clear your inventory?
I want mine EMPTY.

- Ivory Dragon Claw
- Gallus's Encoded Journal
- Elder Scroll
- Attunement Sphere(2)
- Lexicon
- Gauldur Amulet Fragment(2)
- Saarthal Amulet
- Staff of Magnus

I'm playing on the PS3, so I don't have access to console commands.

Comment: If you want to remove them because they are too heavy then you should consider upgrading your stamina.

Answer (score 13):

These all seem like quest items, which can't be removed without console commands or by completing their related quest.  That said, while they *should* be removed when you complete their related quests, I found myself stuck with some of these items after the quests were complete with no way to drop them as well.

Searching the UESP for the items may help you understand which quests these items belong to.  For instance the Elder Scroll can be sold to the librarian at the College of Winterhold ([Urag gro-Shub](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Urag_gro-Shub)).  The Gauldur Amulet Fragment and the Ivory Dragon Claw are part of the quest [Forbidden Legend](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend).

If this sounds like a lot of work, and you're willing to deal with your cluttered inventory, remember that quest items weigh nothing (despite their listed weight).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, I was able to off-load the Elder Scroll onto a bookshelf.  I'm pretty sure the same can be done with any other "book" items you're stuck with - but it's been awhile since I played, so I'm not sure which do or don't work that way.

Same applies to weapons - use weapon racks.

Apparel can probably be dumped on mannequins.

You're probably stuck with "miscellaneous" stuff like the Attunement Spheres and such, but you might want to try dropping them in owned containers or in a follower's inventory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're quite organised with your inventory like myself, this can be a real pain. However, ALL quest items actually have a weight of 0, even the ones that say otherwise. For instance, I just emptied my inventory completely (apart from quest items) and I still have 3 elder scrolls in my inventory. According to the game they weigh 20 each, however my "carried weight" value is 0.

So really my answer would be that yes, although it can be really annoying having them in your inventory, it doesn't really matter anyway. I don't know any way of removing them from your inventory other than what has already been said. Sorry if that didn't make much sense :D

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to save the main quest for last then after you get back from the thalmor embassy you just don't collect it or any other unwanted items from delphine's chest when you collect all your other gear works with all items because the programming of the game prioritizes emptying your inventory over quest items not being deleted, you even temporarily lose the skeleton key.

SAVE BEFORE YOU ACTIVATE THE CHEST in case you accidentally grab the wrong things, this only works once cos this quest isn't repeatable

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quest items such as weapons or shields. You simply equip it and activate a weapon rack/shield rack.

Answer (score 0):

You can sell the elder scroll to the library in Winterhold if you have completed the main quest. I'm not sure if you have to finish the Winterhold quest or not though, I had already done both at the time I sold it.